# Webservices with C#, Ajax, Jquery NOT working with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, web-services

I created a `WebService` in C#. In it I have a method:

I created a `AndroidWebservices.asmx` and a `Default.aspx` with the same method on each page

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public bool CheckLogin(string email, string password)
{
    //Get the User Information
    DB.User cur_user = DB.User.ByEmail(email.Trim());

    if (cur_user.CheckPassword(password)) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

for the Default.asxp page I put in 
`<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>`

and for the AndroidWebService.asmx I uncommented 
`[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`

This service is being run off of `http://localhost:49524/` and also my companys .com domain as well

I created a new directory on a tomcat server:

```
http://  localhost:8080/
```

the code for this is a simple table

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iphone.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/iphone.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1><a></a></h1>
            <div class="loginContainer">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" style="width:100px">
                            <div class="rounded-end">email</div>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <input type="text" id="email" class="login" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" style="width:100px">
                            <div class="rounded-end">password</div>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <input type="password" id="password" 
                                class="login" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="button" class="loginButton" value="login" 
                    onclick="loginCheck(); return false;"/>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function loginCheck() {

    var u = $('#email').val();
    var p = $('#password').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:49524/mobile/Android/Default.aspx/CheckLogin",
        data: JSON.stringify({email: u, password: p}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

The things I've tried:

```
dataType: "json"
```

Returns nothing.

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

Returns the page.. i.e.

```
"<!doctype><html> ...... "
```

Whenever i run the `Default.aspx` as my url the function returns the html/text of the page, i can put the code plus the + querystring in the URL and i get the page back.. but no data
It doesn't seem to be calling the method but rather just returning the page.. as stated above.. 
What I am after is returning a true or a false to ensure the login of the user to proceed to the next page.

I do appreciate people commenting and I had to go back to the office before working on it again.  I will mark a accepted answer as soon as I get one that works.

Comment: also i run with the console on, so i know when i get a same-origin-error

Comment: It doesn't look like you are _returning_ anything in your `if` block.

Comment: thats a typo, i am returning true or false

Comment: Title and typo fixed with edit and i also posted my full html file

Comment: Shouldn't you be using an `.asmx` for your webservices, rather than an `.aspx`?

Comment: Please tell me you aren't checking login status on the client side?!

Comment: As stated, said i have both.. and both weren't working.. and im using c# to check the login. im just passing authentication back to the client

Comment: Hm, Ok. Still can't see where you wrote that in your OP but that's cool. As long as it is being done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a `$.jsonp plugin` that saved the day It made the ajax call easier.. 
I also had to put this in my webconfig:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that's because you marked your Method as protected. Mark it as public, then try again.

So

```
protected bool CheckLogin(string email, string password)
```

becomes

```
public bool CheckLogin(string email, string password)
```

Comment: this didn't fix the error, but i did make the change because you are right it needs to be public not protected.. but i am still getting the html as a response rather then the boolean.